# Convert complex to polar cord

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Write the following numbers in the polar form $^{}, −<≤$:

$r$ = ?, $\theta$ =?

$$-\dfrac{\sqrt{7}(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}+ i} $$

When i used wolfram I got $r = 2.16025$ and $\theta = -170.264^{°}$. However, when I input this in WebAssign I got the right answer for $r$ but the wrong answer for $\theta$. I then tried doing $tan(-170.264^{°}) =.171579$ (in degree) and $tan(-170.264) = -.710889017$ (in radians), and they were both wrong. I'm lost what should be $\theta$ ?

Comment: why would you take tan(-170.265)?

Comment: Put your software down and draw some pictures. If you sketch $-\sqrt{7} (1+i)$ you can see it makes an angle of 235 degrees anticlockwise from the positive real axis. Similarly, $\sqrt{2} + i$ in the first quadrant makes an angle of 35.26 degrees. If you divide two complex numbers you subtract their arguments which is 189.74 degrees or -170.26 degrees if you measure clockwise from the positive real axis.

Comment: Don't use degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Considering all factors in turn, the modulus will be

$$\frac{\sqrt7\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}$$

and the argument

$$-\pi+\frac{\pi}4-\arctan\frac1{\sqrt2}.$$

($-\pi$ is chosen rather than $\pi$ so that the sum be in the allowed range.)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you can rewrite $\frac{−\sqrt7(1+i)}{\sqrt2+i}$ as $-\frac{\sqrt7+\sqrt14}{3} + i(\frac{\sqrt7 - \sqrt14}{3})$. Then use that $re^{i\theta} = r(cos(\theta) + isin(\theta))$ and you get that $$\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
    r\cos(\theta) = -\frac{\sqrt7+\sqrt14}{3}\\
   r\sin(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt7 - \sqrt14}{3}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$
$$or$$
$$\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
    \tan(\theta) = -\frac{\sqrt7-\sqrt14}{\sqrt7+\sqrt14}\\
   r^2 = \frac{14}{3}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$